# SQL Server Reporting Services 2005 how to create nested groups

Tags: sql-server, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-grouping

I know it's old technology (ancient now), but it's what I have to work with due to work.

I am able to create a Group and report and link it to a textbox to provide a collapsible report, with master data and detail data.

What I want to know, is it possible in SSRS2005 to create another **sub-group** to the first group?

i.e.  `Master record -> Detail -> Sub-details`

Every time I try and add another detail row for example I only get one row of data in the sub-group, because it's tied to the Details Grouping. I cannot explicitly say "report grouped by this other subgroup" (where it offers you to create groups in the Group list).

Yes I am trying to do this in a table.

This is what I am after...

```
[+] Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
    [+] data  data  data  data
        Col1  Col2  Col3 ...
        data  data  data ...
...
...
```

The `[+]` is what I want to set up to allow the expansion of another group within the first group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is not to try and pack too much into one reporting object. In this case the `Table` object.

I managed to have far more flexibility by placing the tables and fields inside a `List` object.

Try these...

- Drop a List item into the report
- Define the Dataset to your main dataset that contains all the data.

**Note:** *For this to work you need a query that have as much as the master and detail data inside as ONE query, so obviously your master data will repeat as deep as it has to, to get to the lowest common dataset, which in my case was the action items per student.*

- The List object will act as the Master data reference for all your other objects inside of it.
- Now you can play! Drop in a few `textboxes` to show the data for the master data you want to only show ONCE per "logical record". I'll let you ponder what that meant!
- Now to show subgroups, you'll need Tables for each one. Drop a `Table` object
- In each table (group) don't specify a dataset, as I said above, all the data comes from the List.
- But for each table, you'll need to define your `Details Grouping`. Go ahead and simply state the group parameters you require for the **sub-group**. So in my case, I want to display ONE row of Students, but any amount of Actions each student has. So place a StudentID for the student and an ActionID for the actions as a combined grouping.
- Repeat the above for any other groups, and define their groupings so you don't get repeatitive data. One table could only have one pivot or group, so just define the index for that inside the `Details Grouping`. Do not use the **Add..** feature to add groups, because you'll be adding groups within subgroups and go into another level again! Beware.

I hope this made sense.